# Android Studio: "could not find method compile<> for arguments [file collection]"

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, libs

I am trying to add `aws-android-sdk-1.6.1-debug.jar` (Amazon Cloud Service) library to my Android Studio project.
So I copied the jar-file to libs-directory, right clicked "Add as library".
Then added the line compile files(`libs/aws-android-sdk-1.6.1-debug.jar`) to the `build.gradle` file and run `gradlew` clean bat from command prompt.
This bat gives error:

```
"could not find method compile<> for arguments [file collection]"
```

Even though the jar-file surely is in the libs-directory.
I also tried: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')` with the same result.
Build in Android Studio gives the same result.

Why the jar could not be found ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but I added the dependencies to the wrong `build.gradle`. You have to add the dependencies to the `AndroidStudioProjects/Project/Project/build.gradle`, ***not*** `AndroidStudioProjects/Project/build.gradle`.